# Insert PageBreak on every occurrence in column A

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'm trying in VBA insert PageBreak on every occurrence of No.2 on worksheet. My worksheets could be more than 1000 (even 10.000) rows and I filtered them with filter:

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$443").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="2", Operator:=xlAnd
```

On filtered rows I have to insert PageBreak and border before cell contain No.2 (so every new page should start with "2" in A cell).

As I have many rows, I could not use loop (Do While or For-Next) because it takes huge time. I need solution that will insert PageBreak in filtered rows.
I tried with "for each cell" but it is not suitable for my needs because it scan every cells in range...

Also, I tried with "Location.Offset(-1, 0).Row" but on sheets with 2000 or more rows for first 5-6 occurrences it works fine and then lose focus and PageBreak seat 2-3 rows before or after cell where is No.2.

So, my question is how fast loop trough filtered rows and before each or put pagebreak and border

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please see code comments for more details, but in essence if I understood correctly what you are asking, this should do:

```vb
Sub addPageBreaks()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet '.Sheets("sheet name")
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

Dim arrData: arrData = ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow) 'assign the first column to an array
Dim R As Long

For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData) 'iterate through the first column data
    If arrData(R, 1) = "2" Then 'or 2 ? 'if there is a match
        ws.Rows(R).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual 'add the page break
    End If
Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like 99% success, with a small changes I can apply this code in my macro...

Many thanks

Comment: What's the 1% not working? I can try to assist further... And if is good enough, I would appreciate the vote up and/or accept the answer.

Comment: There is hierarchy. start with No.1 then come No.2, then 3 and so on (up to 6). Between hierarchical rows there are some rows with staffs belong to previous number. Before everything is 2 header rows.

However, I do not need page break on first No.2 (because there is start), so I moved ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow) to ws.Range("A4:A" & lRow). Also this is just a part of bigger code macro (cca 250 lines).
Rest of code I already done... just stuck on PageBreaks. 
I had solution with for-next or do-while-loop but it takes huge time.
Maybe if you can help, how to detect end of page (automatic PB)

Comment: There are obvious minor tweaks you can do yourself (adjusting starting row being one of them), I've produce the above based on the information given. I mean no offense, but `insert PageBreak on every occurrence of No.2` for me means exactly that. The above should run pretty fast, as it only interacts with the sheet once when reading the data to an array, then for each page break (don't think you can do a "multi pagebreak" at the same time to avoid doing it often). From my testing, takes 1-2 seconds over few thousand rows. Sorry, not familiar with automatic PB.

Comment: However... many thanks for your time... I appreciate it... PS great solution... array didn't even come to my mind...